# three.js error when creating massive amount of point lights

Tags: javascript, three.js

```
//////stars
for (let index = 0; index < 1000; index++) {
    const stargeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1, 24, 24); //make star sphere size
    const starmaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({ color: 0xffffff }); //make star texture
    const star = new THREE.Mesh(stargeometry, starmaterial); //creat the star

    const [starx, stary, starz] = Array(3).fill().map(() => THREE.MathUtils.randFloatSpread(10000));//star random position from -x to positive x
    star.position.set(starx, stary, starz); //set the stars
    this.scene.add(star);//add the stars to the scene

    const light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 2, 50 );
    light.position.set( starx, stary, starz );
    this.scene.add( light );
}
```

**The error given by chrome**

> THREE.WebGLProgram: shader error:  0 35715 false gl.getProgramInfoLog Fragment shader is not compiled.

**Updates: **

at ***index<100*** the code runs smoothly generating the stars with their      respective point lights

at ***index<200*** the loading process is increased dramatically

at ***index<300 and above*** it just gives up and outputs the error.

Comment: Not 100% sure what the problem is, but you definitely don't need to put the SphereGeometry and MeshStandardMaterial inside the for loop.  You don't need to create a new geometry and material for each mesh.  Just initialize the geometry and material outside of the loop once.  After that, you can use the same geometry and material for each new star.

Comment: @isaacsan123 yeah i had them there because i was going to randomize the size of the star and the color of the stars with the point light as well. but after mutiple failed attmpts i just tried if white will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In forward rendering (a common rendering method, and the one three.js uses), there's a limit to the number of dynamic point lights that can exist in a scene, and it's pretty low. Each light significantly increases rendering cost, and hardware limits may be reached as low as ~12. See [this issue](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/8463) for some discussion.

Common workarounds are to bake your lighting offline (e.g. in Blender), or to use emissive materials and a [screenspace bloom effect](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=glow#webgl_postprocessing_unreal_bloom_selective). These don't really cast light onto dynamic objects in the scene, but can look quite good with some planning around the limitations.